# Connect to different database in firebase cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have setup the following cloud function, trying to connect to my production database from my develop project.
The problem is, it doesn't seem to connect to the correct database.

It works when i run the code in a local node script.

is it not possible to connect to databases across firebase projects?

(I'm using the emulator suite for testing)

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true })
const { configurations } = require('../../utils/config')
    
    
export const pro_v3_copyProjectToDev = functions
.region('europe-west3')
.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, async () => {     
      const prodApp = admin.initializeApp(
        {
          credential: admin.credential.cert(configurations['example-prod'].serviceAccount),
          databaseURL: 'https://example-prod.firebaseio.com'
        }, 
        'production'
      );
      
      const projectRefProd = prodApp.firestore().collection('testCollection').doc('test')
      const projectDocProd = await projectRefProd.get()
      const projectDataProd = projectDocProd.data()
      console.log({
        prod: projectDataProd? 'found' : 'notFound'
      })

      res.status(200).send()

    })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize the Admin SDK outside the function so that it initialize once:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true })
const { configurations } = require('../../utils/config')
    
const prodApp = admin.initializeApp(
        {
          credential: admin.credential.cert(configurations['example-prod'].serviceAccount),
          databaseURL: 'https://example-prod.firebaseio.com'
        }, 
        'production'
      );
    
export const pro_v3_copyProjectToDev = functions
.region('europe-west3')
.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, async () => {     
      
      
      const projectRefProd = prodApp.firestore().collection('testCollection').doc('test')
      const projectDocProd = await projectRefProd.get()
      const projectDataProd = projectDocProd.data()
      console.log({
        prod: projectDataProd? 'found' : 'notFound'
      })
    })

    res.status(200).send()
})
```

Comment: I still get the same response

Comment: Did you check if it is not a cors issue?

Comment: It was not.

I ended up using two seperate cloud functions instead